# how to filter the data in array of array in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
 Array ( 
 [0] => Array 
 ( 
   [option_id] => 4638 
   [option_name] => custom plugin chatbot checkbox 
   [option value] => on 
   [autoload] => yes )
 )
```

How to filtering the array to get the value of option_name

Comment: `$test = $yourarray[0]["option_name"];`

Comment: No no using array filter method

Answer (score 0):

Array Filter

```
$new = array_filter($yourarray, function ($var) {
  return ($var['option_name'] == 'custom plugin chatbot checkbox');
});
```