# how to get option value of index 3 by using array filter method in php

Tags: php, wordpress

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 4638
            [option_name] => custom_plugin_chatbot_checkbox
            [option_value] => on
            [autoload] => yes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 4443
            [option_name] => custom_plugin_chatbot_checked
            [option_value] => Checked
            [autoload] => yes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 4502
            [option_name] => custom_plugin_chatbot_Position
            [option_value] => 
            [autoload] => yes
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 4637
            [option_name] => custom_plugin_chatbot_script
            [option_value] => <script src=\"//code-eu1.jivosite.com/widget/eNReHbHbwb\" async></script>
            [autoload] => yes
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 4445
            [option_name] => custom_plugin_chatbot_Value
            [option_value] => 
            [autoload] => yes
        )

)
```

Comment: so how to get 3 indexes option_value from the above by using array filter

Comment: What do you want to use array_filter for, if you already know the index of the array element you want to access?

Comment: This appears to be more or less a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74051969/how-to-filter-the-data-in-array-of-array-in-wordpress - there you did not explain why you'd actually want to use array_filter properly either.

Comment: @CBroe because $element  = $array[3]; is too easy :-) . Probably he wants to extract one element that has a specific value, like the one in option_id, but sincerely I'm getting tired to try to help people by guessing what's in their mind

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* use [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), you can do it like this, with the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` mode parameter.

```php
$filtered_option_array = array_filter( $option_array, function( $key ) {
   return 3 === $key;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY  );
$option_value = $filtered_option_array[0]['option_value'];
```

But, for the task in your question it's wasteful of CPU time to do it the way you show. You can simply do this.

```php
$option_value = $option_array[3]['option_value'];
```

**Pro tip for StackOverflow use**: You'll get better (faster, more practical) answers if you explain *why* you want to do things.

Comment: Thankx for the reply but the above codes are not working

Comment: With respect, *not working* can mean anything from a wrong result to *the server caught fire and the data center burned to the ground*. I'll be happy to help if you do a bit of troubleshooting for me.